# Convertir decimal a fracción

Tags: c, algoritmos

¿Qué método podría utilizar en lenguaje C para convertir un número decimal a fracción? (sin utilizar una función compleja)

Realizar un programa que dado un número entre 0,0001 y 0,9999 (y de no más de 4 cifras decimales), obtenga y muestre la correspondiente fracción irreducible.
Por ejemplo, el número 0,25 se puede obtener a partir de 25/100, o de 2/8, o de 1/4, entre otros. 
La fracción irreducible, está formada por un numerador y un denominador que son primos entre sí. Ej:  1/4

Comment: ¿que has intentado hasta ahora?

Comment: puedes empezar creando el numerador y el denominador de la fraccion inicial, y luego ir reduciendo cada uno de los terminos hasta que sean primos entre si. Una pista: si multiplicas el numero por 10000, tienes el numerador, y el denominador puede ser... (te dejo que lo adivines) :)

Answer (score 8):

1. Te están diciendo que no tiene más de 4 dígitos... multiplicas el número por diez mil para que el número tenga únicamente parte entera.
2. Tras el paso anterior empiezas con la fracción `X/10000`
3. Sabiendo que 10000 se puede descomponer en `2^4*5^4`, trata de verificar cuantos de esos factores pueden dividir al numerador.
4. Ya tienes tu fracción irreducible:

Dicho con números. Ejemplo para 0.25:

```
1. 0.25 * 10000 = 2500
2. fraccion => 2500/10000
3. 2500 mod 2  = 0 => 1250/5000
   1250 mod 2  = 0 =>  625/2500
    625 mod 2 != 0
    625 mod 5  = 0 =>  125/500
    125 mod 5  = 0 =>   25/100
     25 mod 5  = 0 =>    5/20
      5 mod 5  = 0 =>    1/4
4. fraccion irreducible 1/4
```

No te pongo código porque no te va a beneficiar en nada que te den el ejercicio hecho.

Comment: en este caso son 4 digitos, por lo que debe multiplicar por 10000, no por mil. Por favor, corrige tu ejemplo. Gracias

Comment: @Jakala cierto... me quede corto al poner ceros

Comment: Yo lo dejaría hasta el paso 2 indicando que para reducirlo a su mínima expresión puede usar algún algoritmo como el máximo común denominador (GCD)

Comment: Sí, es mucho mejor así, para encontrar la manera de resolverlo yo mismo por medio de las ideas que recibo aquí

Answer (score 0):

Si no me equivoco, yo calcularía el mínimo dividendo primero y luego el divisor, algo así en sucio.

```
int dividendo = 0;
while ((++dividendo*10000)%(int)(x*10000) != 0) {};
int divisor = dividendo/x;
```

Comment: ¡Gracias por el aporte! Me ayudará a encontrar la manera de realizar el programa

Answer (score 0):

aqui tienes un ejemplo ya hecho en c++
[decimal a fraccion c++](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5MsdS3_lDJY)
**PASOS BASICOS PARA CONVERTIR DECIMAL A FRACCION**

> Convertir números decimales en fracciones es muy simple siempre y
>   cuando el decimal sea finito, es decir termina, porque ¡todos los
>   números decimales finitos SON fracciones por su definición! Tienen un
>   denominador de 10, 100, 1000, 10 000 etc.
>
> Si el número decimal tiene UN dígito decimal, el denominador es 10. Si
>   tiene dos dígitos decimales, el denominador es 100. Si tiene tres
>   dígitos decimales, el denominador es 1000. Si tiene cuatro dígitos
>   decimales, el denominador es 10000. Y así en adelante. Si tiene n
>   dígitos decimales, el denominador es 10n.
>
> El numerador de la fracción es el "número original" sin el punto
>   decimal.

Comment: Está buscando una fracción irreducible... no una fracción cualquiera... y además el lenguaje sería C, no C++

Answer (score 0):

si lo que quieres es obtener la fracción podrías hacerlo de la siguiente manera.

Te mostraré varios ejemplos:

```
Con .25
1/.25 = 4 entonces ya tendrías que es 1/4.

Con .0001 
1/.0001 = 10000 entonces sería 1/10000.

Con .5
1/.5 = 2 entonces sería 1/2
```

El caso sería dividir 1 entre el numero que te proporcionan y eso te daría el denominador.